# Serialization of an instance in a method

Tags: java, serialization

I am working on a lab for school and am stuck... my instructions tell me to do the following:

- In class LabSerialization: Add a method called serialize.
- It has no return value and two parameters: demo of type ListVsSetDemo and filename of type String Use a try with resource statement when you serialize the ListVsSetDemo instance
- Save the result in the file name specified In case of an exception print the message provided by the exception object

What I am having an issue with is the second part how do you serialize the instance of ListVsSetDemo?

here is my code

```
package labSerialization;

import java.awt.Color;


public class LabSerialization{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListVsSetDemo demo = new ListVsSetDemo(
            new ColoredSquare(4, Color.RED),
            new ColoredSquare(6, Color.BLUE),
            new ColoredSquare(4, Color.RED),
            new ColoredSquare(8, Color.YELLOW));

    //testDemo(demo);
    serialize(demo, Demo.ser);

};

private static void testDemo(ListVsSetDemo demo) {
    System.out.println("List:");
    System.out.println(demo.getListElements());
    System.out.println("Set:");
    System.out.println(demo.getSetElements());
}
private static void serialize(ListVsSetDemo demo, String fileName){

}
}
```

Comment: The most obvious solution is to use an ObjectOutputStream for serialization.  There is too many examples on the web to mention here.

Comment: ... never the less, here is a good example http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/serialization-in-java.html